# Proof that for every $k > 1$, there exists a language $A_k \subseteq \{0, 1\}^*$ s.t. a DFA accepting $A_k$ has $k$ states but no less

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, proof-techniques

I am trying to prove that for every $k > 1$, there exists a language $A_k \subseteq \{0, 1\}^*$ such that a DFA accepting $A_k$ has $k$ states but no less.

I thought about proving this in two ways: constructively, or by contradiction.

**By Contradiction:** For some $k > 1$, suppose there is no language $A_k \subseteq \{0, 1\}^*$ where a DFA accepting $A_k$ exists with exactly $k$ states but no less. Then any language $L \subseteq \{0, 1\}^*$, that has an accepting DFA with $n$ states, also has an accepting DFA with $n - 1$ states. Extending this reasoning downward, this implies that every $L$ has an accepting DFA with $1$ state. This is a contradiction.

**By construction:** Let $A_k = \{w \in \{0, 1\}^* | w \text{ has } 0^{k - 1} \text{ as a substring}\}$. But now I need to prove that $A_k$ cannot be accepted by a DFA with less than $k$ states. I am unsure of how to do this even though it feels true intuitively.

Is my proof by contradiction valid and is the proof by construction doable? Maybe both are wrong and I need to use some other perspective.

**Attempt 2:**

We can easily construct a DFA with $k$ states, call it $M_k$, that accepts the language $$A_k = \{w \in \{0, 1\}^* | w \text{ has } 0^{k - 1} \text{ as a substring}\}$$

Suppose for contradiction that there exists a DFA, $M_{k - 1}$, accepting $A_k$ with $k - 1$ states. Consider the string $w = 0^{k - 1} \in A_k$, we can apply the pumping lemma because $|w| \geq k - 1$. Thus, the run of $w$ on $M_{k - 1}$ must contain a cycle of length 1 (since $|w| = k - 1$).

Then $M_{k - 1}$ actually accepts strings of the form
$$w' = 0^x \cdot 0^i \cdot 0^z$$
where $i \geq 0$, $x + 1 \leq k - 1$ and $x + z + 1 = k - 1$. Letting $i = 0$, we see $M_{k - 1}$ accepts $0^{k - 2} \not \in A_k$. A contradiction.

This reasoning is applicable to every $M_i$ with $1 < i < k$, so we are done. Is this a correct attempt?

Comment: The conclusion that the run of $w$ on $M_{k-1}$ must contain a cycle of length 1 is wrong. Consider $k = 3$ and a run involving states $q_0,q_1,q_0$.

Comment: Right so, it may have a cycle of length $2$. My argument still holds though, since I can pump down even further, correct?

Comment: If a cycle longer than 1 exists for $0^{k - 1}$, then surely it would not be in $A_k$. In your example, it starts from $q_0$ and ends in $q_0$, which means it would accept $\epsilon \not in A_k$ if your run is accepting.

Comment: The algorithm works, but you have to fix it to accommodate cycles of every length. What you get is essentially the proof of the pumping lemma.

Comment: Would the language $\{ 0^k \}$ be a candidate?

Comment: I think $\{0^{k - 2}\}$ would require $k$ states: $1$ dead state and $k - 1$ states to accept the consecutive string of $k - 1$ $0$'s.

Comment: So couldn't we split $0^{k - 1}$ more generally into $0^a \cdot 0^b \cdot 0^c$ where $a + b \leq k - 1$, $b > 0$ and $0^a \cdot (0^b)^i \cdot 0^c \in A_k$ for all $i \geq 0$. But letting $i = 0$, then $0^a \cdot 0^c \not \in A_k$ because $a + c < k - 1$. This is a contradiction. @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Right, the argument works, and it is basically the proof of the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach doesn't quite work. If it is not the case that for any $k$ there is some language that requires exactly $k$ states, then all you know is that there exists a *single* $n$ such that every $n$-state DFA can be reduced to an equivalent DFA with fewer states.

The second approach does work, and requires a lower bound technique such as the pumping lemma (the pumping constant is the number of states) or Myhill–Nerode theory. Try the following language: all words whose length is a multiple of $k$.

Comment: I added my second attempt to my question, would greatly appreciate knowing if it is correct. @Yuval Filmus